# Sobre la etimología discutida de la palabra "droga"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

La palabra *droga* es de esas cuyo origen parece estar discutido en todas partes. Aprovechando que la palabra parece tener el mismo origen en todas las lenguas en las que aparece, consultando [su etimología en la web de Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/drug) leo (y traduzco):

> [...] del francés antiguo *droge* "suministro, provisión" (siglo XIV), a su vez de origen desconocido, tal vez del holandés medio o del bajo alemán *droge-vate* "barriles secos" o *droge waere* "productos secos", y específicamente drogas o especias, con el primer elemento confundido por la palabra para designar al contenido [...] o porque las medicinas consistían mayormente en hierbas secas.

Y aclara específicamente que:

> El mismo origen dio lugar al español e italiano *droga* y al sueco *drog*.

La web francesa del CNRTL [parece opinar lo mismo](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/drogue):

> Palabra de origen discutido; entre las muchas hipótesis la más probable es que provenga del neerlandés medio *droge vate* "barriles secos" a partir de los cuales, por substantivación, *droge* se tomó como la descripción de los contenidos, "productos secos; drogas".

La [etimología contemplada en etimo.it](http://www.etimo.it/?term=droga) es la misma que propone Corominas, la cual transcribo:

> Palabra internacional de historia oscura, que en castellano parece procedente del Norte, probablemente de Francia. El origen último es incierto; quizá sea primitiva la acepción 'cosa de mala calidad', S. XV, y proceda de la palabra céltica que significa 'malo' (bretón *droug*, galés *drwg*, irlandés *droch*), que se habría aplicado a las sustancias químicas y a las mercancías ultramarinas, por el mal gusto de aquéllas y por la desconfianza con que el pueblo mira toda clase de drogas.

Viendo todo esto uno se queda con la idea de que el origen de la palabra se pierde en algún lugar de Europa central. Y sin embargo, [aquí es cuando llega la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ECdTcOk) y se marca un *[se han perdido todos menos yo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eD9A6d-uHs)*:

> Del ár. hisp. **ḥaṭrúka*; literalmente 'charlatanería'.

Resulta curioso que el consenso principal sea que la palabra tenga un origen centroeuropeo y la RAE se desmarque diciendo que viene del árabe, y además de una palabra con una relación incierta con las drogas (entendidas como se hacía en el siglo XVI). En ediciones anteriores la RAE coincidió con el origen centroeuropeo (1899: "Del anglosajón *drug*, seco, árido, p.p. de *drigan*, secar"; 1914: "Del neerlandés *droog*, seco"), luego pasó al árabe (1956: "Del árabe *dawa'*, medicina") y posteriormente decidió que no se conocía el origen (1992: "De origen incierto"). En 2001 se estableció la etimología actual.

Así que pregunto: ¿qué motivos tiene la RAE para asegurar este origen de la palabra? ¿Cuáles son sus fuentes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motivos, ni idea; fuentes, los trabajos del recientemente nombrado académico Federico Corriente, que menciona dicha etimología en su discurso de entrada:

> **Droga**, por ejemplo, viene del árabe hispánico *ḥaṭrúka* (literalmente charlatanería); faltriquera, de *ḥaṭrikáyra* (lugar para bagatelas) y andrajo, de *ḥaṭráč* (necio, pelagatos). Todas, explicó Corriente, derivan de *ḥaṭr*, la pronunciación andalusí de una raíz que significa parloteo o cháchara. Por eso, algunas de esas voces tienen que ver con algo falso, pretencioso o inútil, y así llegaron también a dialectos del norte de África, probablemente de mano de emigrantes andalusíes.
>
> <sub>[Fuente](https://elpais.com/cultura/2018/05/18/actualidad/1526648485_100200.html)</sub>

Digo que motivos ni idea, pero vaya, entiendo que el motivo es que la RAE comparte los resultados de estos estudios (supongo que, si no diesen credibilidad a las investigaciones del Sr. Corriente, no lo habrían nombrado académico).